# How to transmit a single image layer for reconstructing the image later on?

Tags: image, docker

Since docker images are made of layers and every image created by a DockerFile basically is a collection of layers (one layer per DockerFile line), I wonder if it is possible to extract relevant layers, transmit those and reconstruct the image using these layers along with a base image.

This way securely creating individual images on the server, transmitting only the relevant changes and reconstructing the resulting image would be a very good option for a variety of scenarios - including the one we are contemplating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple straight version I used is to export the docker container / image which basically collapses all layers into a single layer. By comparing two different images (base image + current image) one can easily compute the file-system diff and create a file-system "patch" that can be distributed and used based on the base image to recreate the current image. All left is to commit the current container and we are done.

Comment: Hi I have similar question so I found your Q/A here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78038349/patch-docker-image-using-docker-volume  but I didn't quite follow how you did here. Can you take a look at my question ?

Answer (score 0):

Docker's file system and layer management is smart enough to do this for you.

Consider this scenario, for example... create a Dockerfile `FROM node:6.9.5` and add some new configuration or libraries or whatever. publish the resulting image to Dockerhub... call it "my-user/my-image" just for an example.

Now go to another computer that already has the `node:6.9.5` image on it. Create a new Dockerfile that builds `FROM my-user/my-image`. When you build this image, Docker will not download the `node:6.9.5` image again, if you already have it downloaded.

Here's the thing, though... Docker image layers are explicitly tied to each other.

If you have 3 layers in an image (layer-a, layer-b, layer-c), you can't extract layer-b alone. that doesn't make sense, because layer-b relies on the exact state of layer-a for it to work. similarly, layer-c relies on layer-b to work.

each successive layer is only a difference between the previous layer and the result of the next instruction from the Dockerfile.

so the idea of what you're trying to do - to extract layers - both doesn't work the way you might be thinking, and is already handled by Docker itself.

Comment: The idea is that I am certain for example that layer-a is already present on the client (remote) site and therefore the server just sends layer-b and layer-c. I just want to figure out if it is possible and how to get such kind of a behavior. 

The idea is mostly to have a 100MB image, apply certain configuration stuff and a very minor change but since it involves some expensive operations along with a secret bee-dance, I do not want to (can not) do the process itself on the client side.

Also logging and testing of this mechanism would be much more easier as well.

Comment: > "The idea is that I am certain for example that layer-a is already present on the client (remote) site and therefore the server just sends layer-b and layer-c"

This is how Docker works, when you "docker pull" an image from a Docker repository. if the server already has layer-a and layer-b, docker will only download layer-c when you "docker pull" the updated image.

Comment: There is no way to emulate this functionality?

Comment: Too bad you didn't get an answer. I'd like manual control over the layer transfer process without using docker due to network issues. I think this would require manually fiddling with the contents of the overlayfs.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **docker history** is what you are looking for. It gives you each layer, change by change with the commands that have triggered them:

```
docker history myimagename
be51b77efb42        8 days ago          /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install    338.3 MB
4b137612be55        6 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD jessie.tar.xz in /        121 MB
```

see: [docker history](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/#usage)

Comment: Can I extract a single layer (binary wise) and reapply it on the other layer? In this scenario you have an internet transport in-between.

Comment: Well, some layers can be extracted with plain command line tools from the report above, and re-applied elsewhere, but others depend on local filesystem and cannot be applied remotely. The former also only with the assumption of the base image being compatible. Looks to me like you need something more like ansible.