# "patch" docker image using docker volume?

Tags: docker, patch

Our base docker image is stable and  a bit large (for historical reason). Every time we have a new release we just update a few files in it. So the updated Dockerfile is like following,

```
FROM base-image
RUN mkdir /tmp/patch -p
COPY patch.tgz /tmp/patch/ # patch.tgz contains the new release files
RUN cd /tmp/patch && tar zxf patch.tgz && bash -e -x ./install.sh
RUN rm /tmp/patch -rf
```

Because our customer has limited access to the internet, sending the updated docker image file to them is always painful (because of the file size). I am thinking about how to optimize this process.

One method come to my mine is to use **docker volume**. First, create a docker volume to contain the updated files; second, using `docker run --volumes-from patch base`, then I just need to send the docker volume to my customer every time we have a new release. Because the docker volume only contains my updated files, the image size is much smaller.

```
1. docker create -v /patch --name patch some-base
2. docker run --volumes-from patch my-base
```

I know this may not be the intended use case for docker volume but it seems workable. So can anyone shed some light on it or come up with a better idea for my situation ?

Comment: Since you are already using a patch to build the image, can you just let your customer build the image?

Comment: Sadly, no. My customer is a bit old fashion and tells us that docker is too new, too advanced for us so I don't want to learn/touch that, it is all yours. lol

Comment: How is using volumes better?

Comment: lol, ok I update my question. But I have not tested this so I am open to any suggestion.

Comment: I mean: 1. Because the image is built using the patch upon the base image, the size is also small.  2. You said your customer doesn't want to learn Docker, but I'm wondering why your customer is willing to learn how to use volumes but not how to build images.

Comment: "Because the image is built using the patch upon the base image" so the size is also **large** and that is the problem I want to address in the first place.

Comment: The total image size is large. But Docker images consist of layers. If only the patch is changed and the base image is not, then the additional layers are not large. You send the patch not the whole image to the customer each time the patch is updated. And the changed layers with a single base image, not two complete images, are stored on the customer's disk. Outdated layers can be cleaned via `docker system prune`.

Comment: Are you using a registry to store the images? In that case the end user would only need to download the new layers, which will most likely be very small.

Comment: How would you support the application if your end users are running the images, but replacing arbitrary bits of code with volume mounts?  If they reported an issue, how would you tell what version (or combinations of versions) they're using?  If you did attempt this approach, I'd probably just distribute the patch content as a tar file, rather than trying to `docker create` a container that doesn't need to run.

Comment: In addition to the other comments, you increase your image size slightly with the `RUN rm /tmp/patch -rf` step. It doesn't delete anything from the image layers, only hides the content from the rendered view at runtime.

Comment: @DavidMaze "if your end users are running the images, but replacing arbitrary bits of code with volume mounts? " that won't happen as far as I can see, they don't want to touch any docker stuff (as I said in other comments, they are a bit "old fashion"). Using a tar file as you said would have the problem that when my docker restarts, the updated files are gone so I have to untar again.  But again I am open to any suggestion because there seems to only kluge solution here.

Comment: We use registry to store the images. So if the internet access is not a problem then it is indeed "the end user would only need to download the new layers" but as I said in my question that is not the case. It has happened many times that we have to use portable hard disk (I know, that is pretty dumb) to copy the docker image to customer site and that is why I have this question in the first place.